# Online sound is always low

Tags: mixing, behringer, streaming

we are broadcasting live on Facebook via OBS which receives audio input from a Scarlette 2i2 interface from a Behringer x18 mixer. We have the LR outputs to live speakers in our venue and we have one mono connection to the Scarlette which goes to a pc or mac to stream via OBS. The sound is either clipped real bad when the music is playing or it's too low when someone is just speaking. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What levels do you get for music and speech on the Behringer and OBS meters? If you each listen via headphones rather than speakers can you get the levels to match? What is the source of the music? How are your microphones arranged?

Comment: Why just one mono connection to the PC? How does the mono signal sound on the PC, before it's streamed?

Comment: @GrahamNye I think you're right, i think i need to listen to the tracks individually, i'm new to mixing so forgive me

Comment: @n00dles i have a 2i2 which will take two lines and I have 6 output bus from xr-18 BUT i only have on xlr cable AND we're running cables all over the place and it's getting messy

Answer (score 2):

By using an aux send you can mix the volumes of each channel to the proper level (also labeled as Bus 1-6 on the XAir app)

Comment: agreed and i'm doing that, the problem is the sound from the mic is getting washed out by the music and so the overall gain is being turned down on the pc/obs THEN when the music is stopped the voice only segment of the live stream is very low and the overall gain has to be raised. the real problem is that i'm running two mixes, the one for the venue and the online one. it's really hard to hear the online sound while running the live sound. we only have ONE person to do this work and it's done IN the venue. so that may be the problem too

Comment: @ChrisHayes are you using only one microphone for everything?

Comment: @ChrisHayes On my church PA we manage 3 mixes with a single operator, from a rota generally with limited PA experience. We have a recording mix, with everything, an induction loop feed (for hearing aids) with everything but using a different balance via an FX output, and the live PA feed which omits the congregational singing mics by appropriate selection of group feeds. Key here is to sort out your routing beforehand (which doesn't change) and set the gain controls on each channel so that you get the required level with the channel fader at 0 dB. During the event your operator ...

Comment: @ChrisHayes ... can just use the channel faders to bring up active channels. We have multiple mics so we don't have to make fast, large level changes on a single channel. Have you got the X AIR and Facebook/OBS interfaces on different devices or, at least, screens? Where is the music coming from? Is it pre-recorded or are you mixing it live through the x18?

Comment: @ChrisHayes We don't however mix a live band through our current setup. When we had one we used a separate mixer and operator for them.